# TweepError: [{'code': 144, 'message': 'No status found with that ID.'}]

Tags: python, text, tweets

Hey I am using tweets ID to extract the tweet but facing this error `TweepError: [{'code': 144, 'message': 'No status found with that ID.'}]`. I have tried many other tweets id but the error is the same.

My code:

```
id=591902698594701314
import tweepy
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

tweet = api.get_status(id)
print(tweet.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

No problem with the implementation, just that the id is invalid. Try different id.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting a similar error :

```
TwitterError: [{'code': 144, 'message': 'No status found with that ID.'}]
```

Seems like many of the IDs return it for me when I run this code:

```
import twitter
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token_key, access_token_secret)
api.VerifyCredentials()
tweet = api.GetStatus(tweet_ids[420])
print(tweet)
```

**I believe it's throwing this error because many tweets are either deleted by users or the profiles themselves have been deleted.**

Answer (score 0):

This error `TwitterError: [{'code': 144, 'message': 'No status found with that ID.'}]` is because the json return `id` and `id_str` so you must use `id_str` to retweet!